# PHP 'not equal to' multiple categories

Tags: php

I'm trying to target all categories in WooCommerce that aren't 'Coffee','Subscription for Me' or 'Gift Vocuhers'. So, any category apart from these three should display the `<h3>` tag.

The code below works when I target any category apart from 'Coffee':

```
<? if ($categoryName != "coffee") : ?>
    <h3><? echo $product["title"]; ?></h3> 
<? endif; ?>
```

However, when I try to target eliminate multiple categories, it doesn't work. How can I adjust the first piece of code to allow multiple categories to be ignored?

My attempt (not working):

```
<? if ($categoryName != "coffee" || "subscription-for-me" || "gift-vouchers") : ?>
    <h3><? echo $product["title"]; ?></h3> 
<? endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: `if ($categoryName != "coffee" || "subscription-for-me" || "gift-vouchers")` that isn't how it works. You need to check them separately, or use an array and check if any are in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more extendable version and possibly cleaner could be to use `in_array()` like so:

```
<? if (!in_array($categoryName, ["coffee", "subscription-for-me", "gift-vouchers"])): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $product["title"]; ?></h3> 
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should use `&&` instead.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/devukozonecoffee/public_html/wp-content/themes/ozonecoffee_2016/taxonomy-product_cat.php on line 196

Comment: Any idea why this error is coming up @Daniel_Waghorn?

Comment: There was a missing bracket on the `if` statement. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, this does now work correctly, but Dreamweaver is still highlighting it as a PHP error. Presumably this means there is still something not quite right?

Comment: The issue appears to be with the [] brackets. If these are removed the error is gone, but it does break the code. If there are any suggestions you might have it would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be an error elsewhere in your code; `php -l` reveals that the code has no errors. It's a false positive from Dreamweaver which isn't really a proper PHP aware IDE. You could try replacing the square brackets to `array("coffee", "subscription-for-me", "gift-vouchers")` but it still represents an array.